# Cloudant Query on dynamic index object

Tags: json, cloudant

I would like query using the selector for the below JSON object. Based on "Type" my Msgs array displays details.i.e if Type is PAM ,Msgs array will have 'PAMDetails' object. if Type is NAS then NASDetails. Only one type will arrive in the json object. My requirement is to get documents for a given 'LotNumber' and 'messageDate' prior 30 days documents. I tried with default cloudant query but struggling to write the selector for this dynamically creating PAMDetails/NASDetails. tried with Msgs.[].MessageDate but failed to get docs.

```
{
  "_id": "65c5e4c919871f7365f4d814f6e4783g",      
  "Type": "PAM",    
  "LotNumber": "11680555",    
  "Msgs": [
    {   
      "PAMDetails": {
        "MessageDate": "2017-01-19"          
      }   
    },{   
      "PAMDetails": {
        "MessageDate": "2017-01-21"          
      }   
    }
  ]
}
```